# Convert JSON-text (date) to a new dateformat c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recieve it like this/the json looks like this:

`2016-09-04 14:00:00`

And I wish to recieve it monthly instead so if we take the above as an example I only want the month so in this case:

`09`

I loop out the dates via a loop:

```
var getDates = await phpApi.getinfo();

string foreachedDates;

foreach (var theitems in getDates["results"])
{
    foreachedDates = theitems["end_date"].ToString();
}
```

How can I change `foreachedDates`-string `2016-09-04 14:00:00` to the month instead so `09` only?

Comment: Why are you not deserializing it into your own object?

Comment: I haven't done that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to extract the month and don't care about anything else, you can do it with simple string functions.  Parsing the entire date string shouldn't be necessary.

```
    foreach (var theitems in getDates ["results"])
    {
        var monthString = theitems ["end_date"].ToString().Substring(5,2);
        var monthInt = int.Parse(monthString);
    }
```

Comment: what if the month is nov, dev? 11, 12? can i make it have 01, 02, 03 instead?

Comment: @medvedo You said in your question `the json looks like this`. So it can not be like nov, dev :)

Comment: yea but now with his code above i get the months just fine. 1,2,3,4,5 etc. but what if the month is okt, nov or december that requires two numbers?

Comment: @medvedo Don't you understand? according to your question it can't be like that

Comment: i guess i am not understanding the whole picture no. jason codes works though. but it doesnt work when it is nov, dec for example as it requires 2 numbers

Comment: @medvedo Same to us, We don't understand what your are asking....

Comment: apparently the two people who posted answers did? speak for yourself, lol

Comment: @medvedo But your problem isn't still solved is it? lol

Comment: Well it is. I know how to work around it now. But it could be solved smoother.

Comment: The code posted extracts a 2 char substring.  So it should handle 11, 12 as well as a leading 0.

Comment: Yes it works. Just tested it with nov, dec. Thanks a ton, Jason

Answer (score 1):

Cast like this

```
foreach (var theitems in getDates ["results"])
        {
            foreachedDates = DateTime.ParseExact(theitems ["end_date"].ToString(), "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM");
        }
```

Comment: error: `The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.`